# MongoDB Fails to Upgrade on Linux Mint, Post-Installation Script Returned Error

Tags: linux, mongodb

So I ran into a fun little problem today with updating my instance of MongoDB using the package manager.  Every time it tried to update, it would give me an error of `E: mongodb-10gen: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1`

Everything else upgrades fine in the package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was saying it wasn't able to sucessfully run the post-installation script; essentially it couldn't restart the database after it was upgraded.  In my case, that's because the DB was already running.  Shutting down and upgrading normally fixed my issue and allowed my package manager to fully upgrade.

- `mongo`
- `use admin`
- `db.runCommand('shutdown')`
- `exit` (after this you should be inside the shell)
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Voila, now your MongoDB install should be upgraded and running.